# Ubuntu 20.04 - Need some help **No experience with Ubuntu**

Tags: server, internet

I need some help. I am completely new to Ubuntu. My experience is with Windows Server. I spun up a new server with Ubuntu server 20.04 in vSphere. The install went smooth, a static IP was assigned to it. I can ping it from my windows machine. However, the issue's I am having is the box cannot connect to the internet. I tried to run ifconfig, but I get the error:

```
Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Since I am not connected to the internet, I cannot install the package. This is on a domain. Do I have to join the box to the domain first? My experience with Windows is that it doesn't need to be on the domain to get on the internet. I'm assuming Ubuntu is the same? The leads me to my other issue, how do you join an Ubuntu box to a Windows domain environment? I ran across some articles, but none worked for me because of my initial issue with not being able to get on the internet. Please advise.

Performed ip addr and got the following:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:50:56:8f:8d:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.x.x.x/24 brd 10.x.x.255 scope global noprefixroute ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe8f:8d89/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The 10.x.x.x/24 address is the correct one I gave it. I'm able to ping the IP from my Windows workstation, but cannot do anything from within the Ubuntu box.

Now in the network settings, there is the Routes section, under Address and DNS. Does that part need to be filled in?

@user535733 Sorry. I should've mentioned it. Yes, I am using the GUI interface. I have no experience in Ubuntu but I've been tasked to get this going.

To add more context to this, I verified the Ubuntu's internet connectivity by opening FireFox and going to YouTube/Amazon and the pages failed to load. I am getting a "Cannot connect to the server at www.Youtube.com" I am also seeing a question mark over the ethernet icon that is located in the upper right hand of the desktop.

Comment: ifconfig is deprecated, and has been replaced with `ip`. Run `ip addr` to see all your interfaces, their status, and the IP address assigned to each.

Comment: What do I need to do to get it to connect to the internet? I'm approaching this angle from a Windows Server perspective and so far nothing has worked. It seems I might be missing some packages?

Comment: Look at your output for ens160: IP addr 10.x.x.x/24. Is that an appropriate IP address for the network? Is that the static IP you expected?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator sorry new here...not used to this kind of format. I'm more used to the traditional forums. Thank you.

Comment: Set it to DHCP to see if I can get it to connect and update and download the repositories that way, but still is not connecting. Ran across another thread to run: sudo dhclient enp0s25, but that doesn't work either. I get a sudo: hdclient: command not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Looked in /etc/netplan but I have no .yaml files.